# JS: How to find double question mark in string

Tags: javascript

E.g. I have sample string as below:

```
var str = "Visit ? W3Schools ??"
```

I want to find the double question mark "??" exist in that string.

Anyone can help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract it? Or just know if it exists in the string?

Comment: just know if it exists in the string ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf('??')`:

```js
var str = "Visit ? W3Schools ??";
console.log(str.indexOf('??'));
```

> **NOTE** that if you use `includes()` it will not work in IE browser.